# Error while using md-input-container

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have created a Angular 2 material app as per link https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md.

I am able to use `<md-card>, <md-toolbar>, <md-input>` etc. But when I use `<md-input-container>`, it is throwing error as

```
zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'md-input-container' is not a known element:
```

Here are the detail from packages.json,

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.11-3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.1.4-2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
```

How I can fix this?

https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/input says that md-input is deprecated and use md-input-container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might not work yet, because those [changes](https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/ca2046b967c942d8dfdc83948d266e740c2447c7) didn't made into [2.0.0-alpha.11](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/2.0.0-alpha.11) release yet.

https://github.com/angular/material2/compare/2.0.0-alpha.11...master

We will have to wait till the next release for npm to cointain this, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: So md-input-container not available as of now? I see lot of examples with md-input-container, is it only for JS? not for Typescript?

Comment: I think those examples just won't work in `@angular/material@latest` npm release yet. The same was with `textarea md-autosize`. I had to wait for the release containing it.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

app.module.ts

```js
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
...
@NgModule({
imports: [
MaterialModule
]
})
```

app.component.html

```html
<md-input-container>
<input mdInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
</md-input-container>
```

The key thing here is to make sure that you add this in the head of your index.html.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```